# PDO Exception when binding parameters in an UPDATE query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bind

I have the following SQL UPDATE query using PDO and binding two parameters, but I get an error:

```
$updateSql = $con->prepare("UPDATE menu SET '".$field."' = :value WHERE 'id' = :idField");
$updateSql->execute(array(
    ':value' => $value,
    ':idField' => $id));
```

And the error is telling me:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Syntax error next to ''dish' = ? WHERE 'id' = ?'
```

NOTE: The UPDATE is executed correctly, but the script stops running with the Fatal Error.

Comment: try to use `?` instead of `:value` or `:idField`

Comment: @AresDraguna Same error...

Answer (score 1):

You enclosed the column name by single quotes. Remove single quotes.

```
$updateSql = $con->prepare("UPDATE menu SET ".$field." = :value WHERE id = :idField");
```

Comment: and if you want to use quotes, try this: \` \` P.S: Nice catch @voidmain

Comment: @void main - Here is the thing. I realized the UPDATE is being executed correctly, but I still receive that error. Why could that be?